# How to programmatically click a button in an AcroForm pdf using itext?

Tags: java, user-interface, pdf, io, itext

I have an AcroForm pdf file that has few buttons and drop down menus.

I know you can input text into text fields using `form.setField();` method. Can you do the same for regular buttons?

Comment: You can select one or more values in a choice field (I think you are referring to such a field when you say "drop down menu") and you can change the text/icon on a button. But you can't "click a button" e.g. to execute a JavaScript action (or any other action for that matter).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks. And how do you click/select radio buttons and checkboxes?

Comment: That's done with `setField()` too. The trick is to know which values you can pick. See "How to get specific types from AcroFields?" [iText 5](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-get-specific-types-acrofields-pushbuttonfield-radiocheckfield-etc) / [iText 7](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/interactive-forms/itext7-how-get-specific-types-acrofields-pushbuttonfield-radiocheckfield-etc) You need to get the different appearance states.

Comment: You can't do it in iText but there are other Java-based PDF tools available that do actually execute JavaScript in PDF form fields programmatically. You can't "click" a button but you can get the JavaScript associated with the button Mouse Up event, which is where the code usually resides, and then execute that script as though it were running in Acrobat or Reader.